# как сбросить цвет окрасившейся ячейки в datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть datagrid, которвй при поиске выделяет строку , но пои ппюовторном поиске предыдущая строка не сбрасывает цвет

Comment: так же как и задавали. Можно попробовать использовать свойство SelectedItem для грида, а в его методе set добавить обработку для цвета

Comment: Это ведь не выбранный элемент а окрашенный как к нему обращаться?